# Logically Equivalance - Proofs

Tags: logic, proof-writing

In terms of logical statements, is  ($\exists$n $\in$ N)($\forall$ x $\in$ A)(nx >= 1) equal to ($\forall$x $\in$ A)($\exists$ n $\in$ N)(nx >= 1)?

Also consider the following statements

1. $\forall x \in R \exists n \in N \colon nx < 1$
2. $\exists n \in N \forall x \in R \colon nx \ge 1$

Why is the negation of 2. equivalent to 1.?

Also, How do i know if (I): (∀x∈R)(∃n∈N)(nx<1)
(II): (∃n∈N)(∀x∈R)(nx≥1) are logically equivalent?

Comment: No. The first implies the second, but the second does not imply the first.

Comment: (I) (∀x∈R)(∃n∈N)(nx<1)  (II)(∃n∈N)(∀x∈R)(nx≥1) how is the negation of (II) equal to (I)?

Comment: It not that (I) is the negation of (II), it's just that they are not logically equivalent. It's like saying "For every car, there exists a key that will start that car" versus "There exists a key such that every car is started by that key." They are not opposite statements, they are just not necessarily both true or both false.

Answer (score 2):

No, for example: let $A = \{\frac 1 k \mid k \in \mathbb N\}$, $N = \mathbb N$. Then
$$
\exists n \in N \forall x \in A \colon xn \ge 1
$$
is false, since for a fixed $n \in \mathbb N$ we have $\frac 1 {n+1} \in A$ and $n \cdot \frac 1 {n+1} < 1$.
On the other hand
$$
\forall x \in A \exists n \in N \colon nx \ge 1
$$
is true. (Given $x = \frac 1 k \in A$ let $n = k$.)

---

To address your additional question:

It is not true that 2. is (equivalent to) the negation of 1. Instead we have
$$
\forall x \in R \exists n \in N \colon nx < 1 \Longleftrightarrow \neg \left(\exists x \in R \forall n \in N \colon nx \ge 1\right)
$$

Try to prove this on your own and if you get stuck, feel free to ask for additional help.

Comment: (I) (∀x∈R)(∃n∈N)(nx<1) (II)(∃n∈N)(∀x∈R)(nx≥1) how is the negation of (II) equal to (I)?

Comment: I will add this question to your initial post and provide an answer in a moment.

Comment: Thanks that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

> (I) (∀x∈R)(∃n∈N)(nx<1) (II)(∃n∈N)(∀x∈R)(nx≥1) how is the negation of (II) equal to (I)?

The negation of (II) is not (I). The negation of (II) is $(\forall n\in N)(\exists x\in R)(nx<1)$

Comment: How do I now to statements are logically equivalent. Takes take the question above, how would I know if (I) is logically equivalent to the negation of (II)? Would the statements be the same?